# How to wait for ad in the background with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, rpa

Im having a problem while trying to mining a page with selenium and python, as im doing it the script crashes because the ad appears sometimes and sometimes not, and the trigger for me is unkown, I Really dont know what triggers this ad.

Is there a way to wait for it in the background ?

here is the page: https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/petrobras-petr4/historico/

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign. It would help alot. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `hidden` attribute to each `iframe` to make them invisible as follow:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = input('Enter URL to detect ads from: ')

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://'+url)

all_iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")#set the tag name here
if len(all_iframes) > 0:
    print("Ad Found\n")
    browser.execute_script("""
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); 
        for(var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++)
             {
                 elems[i].hidden=true;
             }
                          """)
    print('Total Ads: ' + str(len(all_iframes)))
else:
    print('No frames found')


#You can place your code here, as by now the ad should have been hidden.
```

P.S. Note that not every `iframe` on page is an advertisement!